# Posicionando labels

Tags: java, swing, layout

Estou com dificuldade para adicionar labels em posições distintas, em relação a um campo (`JTextField`). Eu gostaria de colocar um `label` antes do campo, a esquerda, e um segundo `label` em baixo do `JTextField`.

Exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei usar alguns gerenciadores de layout, inclusive o `GridBagConstraints`, porém, não conseguir fazer o que eu desejava. Alguém poderia me dar pelo menos um direcionamento de como fazer ?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TesteLabel extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()
                -> {
            TesteLabel testeLabel = new TesteLabel();
        });
    }

    public TesteLabel() {
        add(addComponent());
        setSize(500, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent addComponent() {
        JPanel painelPrincipal = new JPanel();

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel labelLateral = new JLabel("Label Lateral: ");
        JLabel labelInferior = new JLabel("Label Inferior: ");

        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        //painel.add(labelLateral, jTextField);
        painel.add(labelLateral);
        painel.add(jTextField);
        painel.add(labelInferior, gbc);
        jTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));

        painelPrincipal.add(painel);

        return painelPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui desta forma:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TesteLabel extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(TesteLabel::new);
    }

    public TesteLabel() {
        add(addComponent());
        setSize(500, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent addComponent() {
        JPanel painelPrincipal = new JPanel();

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel labelLateral = new JLabel("Label Lateral: ");

        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc1.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        painel.add(labelLateral, gbc1);

        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = (GridBagConstraints) gbc1.clone();
        gbc2.gridx = 2;
        gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc2.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        painel.add(jTextField, gbc2);

        JLabel labelInferior = new JLabel("Label Inferior: ");

        GridBagConstraints gbc3 = (GridBagConstraints) gbc1.clone();
        gbc3.gridx = 2;
        gbc3.gridy = 2;
        gbc3.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        painel.add(labelInferior, gbc3);

        painelPrincipal.add(painel);

        return painelPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segredo aqui foi utilizar `gridX` e `gridY` como coordenadas para posicionar os componentes, e a constante `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` para forçar o campo de texto ser o último item daquela linha. Usei `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` para que o campo de texto preencha todo o espaço daquela *linhaxcoluna* em que ele se encontra, sem isso ele não se expandirá.

No entanto, não é possivel sobrar aquele espaço na segunda linha com este layout, pois para isso, precisaria ter um componente ali, ocupando o espaço para uma coluna 3. Como o painel só possui 2 colunas, o label inferior vai ficar na ultima coluna.

Você pode ver mais sobre esse layout neste [tutorial da oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#BOTH).